# Cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe). terminal error

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, wget

I've been trying to install windows on an online.net dedibox server through rescue mode.  I've been using the following command:

wget -O- 'http://mirror.joodle.nl/32055487-KS2012R2-Joodle-Template-506980.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda

but I keep receiving the following message:
Cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe).

Can someone point out to me why the pipe is broken? Is it because I have a space somewhere where I shouldn't or an extra character where there shouldn't be?  I've been fiddling with it for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out.  If someone could point out where its messing up I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Similar to question: http://serverfault.com/questions/25779/how-do-i-pipe-a-downloaded-file-to-standard-output-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add `sudo` before `apt-key`, just like this:

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute this command with **`sudo`**.
Best Regards.